# How to set webhook for Viber Java bot using NGROK?

Tags: java, viber

I am traying to set WEBHOOK to viber bot using NGROK but it return 404.
Is it possible in novadays? Considering that ofical java lib is depricated?

```
@Configuration
public class ViberBotConfig {

    @Bean
    ViberBot viberBot() {
        ViberBot viberBot = new ViberBot("MyViberBotWonderfulWorld", "TOKEN");
        try {
            viberBot.listen("/callback");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        // let Viber API know about webhook url
        viberBot.setWebhook("NGROK DOMAIN");
        return viberBot;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.